# Capturing requests to download a file from a certain website?

Tags: python, http, user-interface, browser, python-3.x

I'm designing a program that I'd like to be able to notice when a user clicks on a link to or on a certain set of websites (to download and process a file from that website without the user having to go through the site's interface, download the file with their browser, and feed it into the program).

I've seen similar programs do this, but they work by replacing the `http://` prefix in the URL with something custom that the browser knows to send to the program. That isn't an option here; the site already exists, and I don't have control over it.

The next solution that springs to mind is a browser plug-in, but that's an awfully inelegant way of implementing this; it forces the user to use a certain set of browsers if he wants to use my program, and requires me to write and indeed learn how to write plug-ins for whatever browsers I want to support. What might work is a Greasemonkey script that implements the solution above, but that's still pretty hackish and requires the user to download and install stuff he doesn't really want.

The third solution I can think of is setting the program up as a proxy like some ransomware programs do, but that would be an incredibly nasty hack. I'd rather my program not completely screw over the user's internet connection if there's a problem, nor do I want it to have to run all the time.

One more solution I can think of is more of a compromise; at least in Windows the user ought to be able to click and drag the link into the program window and have it extract the link that way. That is a pretty elegant way to do things, and I'll probably implement it as a fallback, but I'm not sure how it would work under MacOS and it's not quite the "one-click" solution I was going for- the entire point of this program is that it can be used with an absolute minimum of actual user interaction.

The language I intend to implement this in is Python 3.3. Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: If the user isn't going to download and install anything, how on earth do you think your program would capture anything? Your best option is the drag-and-drop option, or a browser plugin.

Comment: You seem to care a lot about being non-invasive, but then you’re trying to randomly intercept link clicks, which is fairly invasive to begin with. You can’t have both, in a sense.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's less about not expecting the user to download and install anything and more about not expecting the user to download and install more than one thing, especially when he doesn't really want the things my program would have to depend on. Would you like it if the 1-kb Python script you downloaded to sort your .JPGs and .GIFs into seperate folders had to download, install, and run Photoshop to do so?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Not randomly; just intercepting very specific link clicks. That is pretty invasive, but if done right it shouldn't be annoying, which is the thing I really want to avoid.

Comment: The purpose of this program is to install and uninstall mods for Kerbal Space Program; a process which ultimately amounts to extracting an archive into a folder. This is already a pretty easy process, though it can get bothersome if you have to do it fifty times on one sitting; the whole point is that it makes an already pretty simple process into a one-step process, and so the amount of effort it takes to drag a link into another window is indeed too high of an amount.

Comment: You might try to explain your scenario in less-abstract terms; it might turn out to be achievable in some other way.